# Is it possible to get a variable inside a method C#

Tags: c#

I want to know if i can get a variable inside the method for example:

### Foo.cs

```
public void Foo()
{ 
   int getme = 1;
}

public void FooGetter()
{ 
   Foo(); //how can i get that variable get me ? without using delegates or anything just using method. Foo:getme?
}
```

Comment: No, this is impossible.

Comment: No, and that's the whole point of defining a variable to be *local* to a method. It can't be seen from outside.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Similar to @Lidaranis, what are you actually trying to achieve with public void Foo()? If the only point of that is to return int getme then why make it void at all?

Comment: im trying to get the variable inside the method and realized that static variables are not applicable for methods thanks for the info guys

Answer (score 1):

You can't straightforward access local variable of one method from another one.

However you can either change `Foo` method return type from `void` to `int` and return this variable:

```
public int Foo()
{ 
   int getme = 1;

   return getme;
}

public void FooGetter()
{
    int getme = Foo();
}
```

or you can return it using `out` parameter modifier:

```
public void Foo(out int getme)
{ 
   getme = 1;   
}

public void FooGetter()
{ 
   int getme;
   Foo(out getme); 
   // at this point getme will contain value assigned in Foo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use method return value.

```
public int Foo() //change this to return type
{ 
   int getme = 1;
   //do something else
   return getme;
}

public void FooGetter()
{
   int result = Foo(); // here you receive variable getme
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: no, that won´t work because your variable is only defined in the scope of `Foo`. However you may add a return-value to `Foo`:

```
public int Foo() { return getMe; }
```

Now you can access the value by calling `Foo()`.

For further reading on scopes read this [arctivle on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).

Alternativly you may create a member of your class:

```
class MyClass {
    int getme;

    void Foo() {
        this.getme = 1;
    }

    void FooGetter() {
        var result = this.getme;
    }
}
```

Now you can call `FooGetter` **after** you´ve called `Foo`.